# avoid " while exporting results of a query into a .csv file

Tags: csv, sqlite, export-to-csv

I have saved 3 profile_names in db. While exporting the results of the given query, i'm getting profile_names containing spaces with double quotes e.g. "gold plan".

```
    sqlite> .mode csv
    sqlite> .output stdout
    sqlite> SELECT profile_name FROM sub_profile_table;
    profile_name
    arup
    "gold plan"
    "very gold plan"
```

Is it possible to get the output like this while exporting query results into .csv file?

```
    profile_name
    arup
    gold plan
    very gold plan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSV output mode quotes values when needed.

As long as you have only a single column, you can use `.mode list`. You can use this also with multiple columns (with `.separator ,`), but that would break if some value actually contains a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .output out.csv
sqlite> SELECT profile_name FROM sub_profile_table;
```